# jQuery Mask замена первой цифры телефона

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть инпут, в который вводится номер телефона. На инпут навешана маска:

```
$('input[name="phone"]').mask("+7 (999) 999-9999");
```

Цель такая, если человеком вводится первая цифра "8" или "7", то в инпуте эти цифры не отображаются. а просто выводится: "+7 (", если остальные цифры, то как обычно.
Как я не пробовал не получается убрать эти самые цифры, т.е. ввожу "7", отображается "+7 (7", с восьмеркой также.
Предположил, что можно переопределить значение инпута в событиях keyup, keydown, keypress и т.п., но не получается. Остановился вот на этом:

```
$('input[name="phone"]').on('keyup', function(ex) {
    var $this = $(this);
    if(ex.which == 55 || ex.which == 56 || ex.which == 103 || ex.which == 104) {
        $this.val('+7');
        $this.mask("+7 (999) 999-9999");
        //$this.trigger('keyup');
    }
});
```

Подскажите, как и возможно ли убрать первую вводимую цифру? 
Попробовал еще возвращать false в функции, но не помогло, просто исчезает маска, пробовал метод unmask применять и играться с ним, но тоже безрезультатно.

Comment: 1. Вы уверены что у вас будут номера только с `+7`? 2. Какая библиотека маски используется?